# How to create a current/load-dependent dc voltage source?

Tags: voltage, current

I'm trying to supply a small device with 5V DC voltage, but for various reasons the power cable needs to be relatively long and therefore has considerable resistance. Predictably, the voltage drops under load by about 1V (i.e. when the device is active), which is undesirable. I tried simply boosting the supply voltage to 6V to compensate for this drop, but it appears that the device itself has some overvoltage protection and will simply not turn on at all in this case. I therefore think that I need a voltage source that increases its voltage in response to the output current. Unfortunately I have no clue how to go about doing something like this and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is called *remote sensing* in power conversion lingo.

Whatever device you're using to generate or regulate the +5V most likely has some sort of voltage feedback arrangement. This feedback point (or points, if there's return sensing as well) needs to be connected to the point at which you want the voltage to be regulated - that is, at the far end of your power cable. This is done with separate connections from the power lines - usually with thin wires. The feedback node is usually high resistance compared to the load resistance, so that the sense draws only a very small current. This allows the remote sense to be long without dropping voltage due to \$I^2 \cdot R\$ losses.

At the regulator end, you usually put a few hundred ohms between the sense line and the power line so that if the sense becomes disconnected, you still have a point of reference for the regulator.

Comment: Thanks, Madmanguruman. I was hoping to find a solution that works by sensing the current in some way (as it's constant anywhere along the supply cable). I wanted to avoid further wires, but it does sound like your suggestion would be a relatively easy option.

Comment: You *could* sense the current at the driving end and boost the voltage accordingly ... this gives your PSU a "negative output impedance" ... but it is a very fragile design in two respects. (1) it is an open loop compensation, intimately tied to knowledge of the cable impedance - replace the cable and it is WRONG! and (2) connecting a negative impedance to a reactive load is a classic way to build an oscillator... it can (perhaps) be made stable but it's not pretty.

Comment: 30+ years of the industry using remote sense lines is all the proof I personally need. Keep it simple...

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 standard techniques. One requires support at the power supply end and more cabling : if your power supply supports "remote sensing" it will have a "sense" input next to the power output. As "Madmanguruman" says, there ought to be similar sensing on the 0V return too. One problem with remote sensing is that it can suffer from stability problems if the cables are too long (and inductive!)

Simpler is to boost the supply to 6V or more as you have done, and add a "LDO" (low dropout) regulator at the consumer end. Make sure you have enough voltage to cover both the cable loss and the LDO regulator "margin" at max current.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Brian. I had thought of this as well, but for various reasons I'd like to avoid putting a local voltage regulator close to the device, and not just because it feels like cheating ;-)